# Taking screenshot C++ directx gets black image

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx, screenshot, direct3d9

I'm trying to take a screen capture with directx. I tried code from several pages that explains how but always get a black screen shot. If someone can help me I will be grateful.

my code is:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IDirect3DDevice9* g_pd3dDevice;
    //SaveScreenShot("test.bmp",D3DXIFF_BMP);   
    IDirect3DSurface9* pSurface=NULL;
    //IDirect3DSurface9* pSource=NULL;
    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = FALSE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = 1280;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = 1024;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = GetDesktopWindow();
    d3dpp.FullScreen_RefreshRateInHz=0;
    d3dpp.MultiSampleQuality=0;
    IDirect3D9* direct=Direct3DCreate9(D3D9b_SDK_VERSION);
    direct->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                         D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                         GetDesktopWindow(),
                         D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                         &d3dpp,&g_pd3dDevice);


    //g_pd3dDevice->GetRenderTarget(0,&pSource);
    g_pd3dDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(1280, 1024,
        D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &pSurface, NULL);
    g_pd3dDevice->GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface);
    /*g_pd3dDevice->GetRenderTargetData(pSource,pSurface);
    g_pd3dDevice->GetRenderTargetData(pSource,pSurface);*/
    D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile("Desktop.jpg",D3DXIFF_JPG,pSurface,NULL,NULL);
    pSurface->Release();
    //pSource->Release();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try adding some error handling and perhaps you will get to know why it fails.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the code shows a black screenshot because you are trying to save the front buffer, which at the time you call D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile() is empty. You should either call IDirect3dDevice9::Present() first, or do the following:

- Draw whatever you want on the device's back buffer
- Get the back buffer's DC handle (source)
- Use GDI by calling BitBlt, to copy the contents of the source DC to a destination DC, which you can then write to a file, print etc.

Direct3D will not give you the contents of what you see on the screen (at least to my experience!), only the contents of the client area of the window for which it was created.